# can i display the tcp status in wireshark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

Im using tcpdump to generate some captures between a client, proxy and an origin server.
I was wondering if its possible to either within wireshark or thru some param to indicate in each packet what TCP status the device is at e.g. ip 10.20.30.34 -- CLOSE_WAIT etc..

Comment: Not a Wireshark answer, but netstat -ano will show you connections, port numbers and tcp socket state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible within Wireshark (and AFAIK not within tcpdump either).